# Webstorm: how to disable node_modules debugging

Tags: webstorm

I use the following settings:
[image]

and it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to [WEB-16711](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16711); it's fixed in WebStorm 11.

Answer (score 0):

I turn off all Plugins (press Ctrl+Alt+S) and then turn on only required (NodeJs and etc.) and all works good.